# Strange output when listing installed software with psinfo

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I'm trying to learn more about the Sysinternals PsTools utilities. Today, I ran `psinfo -s` on my Windows XP SP3 system, and the following entries were at the end of the list:

[image]

Is this a known bug in `psinfo` or something else?

Comment: What happens when you run appwiz.cpl?  Is this corrupted as well?

Comment: @jftuga No.  Nothing appears wrong in `appwiz.cpl`